# Error returning from function after adding record

Tags: postgresql

I am adding a comment, you need to return the number of the added comment

```
DO
    $do$
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM COMMENTS WHERE PARENT_ID = '791') THEN 
                UPDATE COMMENTS SET HAS_CHILD = TRUE WHERE COMMENT_ID = '791';
            END IF;
            RETURN QUERY
            INSERT INTO COMMENTS(USER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, PARENT_ID, REPLY_ID, USER_NAME, USER_AVATAR, USER_COMMENT, DATE_COMMENT, HAS_CHILD)
                VALUES('7', '40', 791, 791, 'Name', 'https://...', 'like product', '1552899310', FALSE)
                    RETURNING COMMENT_ID;
        END
    $do$
```

But I get an error `ERROR:  cannot use RETURN QUERY in a non-SETOF function`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't return a value from a `DO` block

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name How can I return the value?

Comment: You need a real function to do that, or don't use a DO block at all

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name How to do without a DO block?

Comment: Please show us your function.

Comment: @Lajos Arpad All that I have I showed above, I just need to return the number of the added comment

Comment: I do not see any CREATE FUNCTION in your code. Read more here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-createfunction.html

Comment: You have an anonymous DO block, not a function. A DO block can not return anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function shouldn't return a query but a single variable:

```
INSERT INTO COMMENTS(USER_ID, PRODUCT_ID, PARENT_ID, REPLY_ID, USER_NAME, USER_AVATAR, USER_COMMENT, DATE_COMMENT, HAS_CHILD)
VALUES('7', '40', 791, 791, 'Name', 'https://...', 'like product', '1552899310', FALSE)
RETURNING COMMENT_ID INTO var;

RETURN var;
```

Comment: I added a variable, but now gives an error `RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning void`. What is the reason for this?